# Counting words / lines in Ruby

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, file

I solved [this problem](http://www.sebnozzi.com/244/beginner-words-and-lines/) in Ruby:

> Write an utility that takes 3 command-line parameters P1, P2 and P3.
>   P3 is OPTIONAL (see below) P1 is always a file path/name. P2 can take
>   the values:
>
> - “lines”
> - “words”
> - “find”
>
> Only P2 is “find”, then P3 is relevant/needed, otherwise it is not.
>
> So, the utility does the following:
>
> - If P2 is “rows” it says how many lines it has
> - If P2 is “words” it says how many words it has (the complete file)
> - If P2 is “find” it prints out the lines where P3 is present

My solution looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def print_usage
  puts "Usage: #{$0} <file> words|lines"
  puts "       #{$0} <file> find <what-to-find>"
end

class LineCounter
  # Initialize instance variables
  def initialize
    @line_count = 0
  end
  def process(line)
    @line_count += 1
  end
  def print_result
    puts "#{@line_count} lines"
  end
end

class WordCounter
  # Initialize instance variables
  def initialize
    @word_count = 0
  end
  def process(line)
    @word_count += line.scan(/\w+/).size
  end
  def print_result
    puts "#{@word_count} words"
  end
end

class WordMatcher
  # Initialize instance variables, using constructor parameter
  def initialize(word_to_find)
    @matches = []
    @word_to_find = word_to_find
  end
  def process(line)
    if line.scan(/#{@word_to_find}/).size > 0   
      @matches << line
    end
  end
  def print_result
    @matches.each { |line|
      puts line
    }
  end   
end

# Main program
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME

  processor = nil

  # Try to find a line-processor
  if ARGV.length == 2
    if ARGV[1] == "lines"
      processor = LineCounter.new
    elsif ARGV[1] == "words"
      processor = WordCounter.new
    end
  elsif ARGV.length == 3 && ARGV[1] == "find"
    word_to_find = ARGV[2]
    processor = WordMatcher.new(word_to_find)
  end

  if not processor
    # Print usage and exit if no processor found
    print_usage
    exit 1
  else
    # Process the lines and print result
    File.readlines(ARGV[0]).each { |line|
      processor.process(line)
    }
    processor.print_result
  end

end
```

My questions are:

- Is there a more Ruby-esque way of solving it?
- More compact, but still readable / elegant?

It seems checking for correct command-line parameter combinations takes up a lot of space...

Contrast it to the Scala version found here:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93a975cb7aba6dae5a91#file-counting-scala

Comment: If you are satisfied with any of the answers, you should select the one that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some notes:

- Those counter classes are probably overkill, keep it simple.
- Ruby is an OOP language, but it's not necessary to create a bunch of classes  for simple scripts like this.
- Idiomatic: `if not x` -> `if !x`
- Idiomatic: `{ ... }` for one-line blocks, `do`/`end` for multi-line.

I'd write:

```
fail("Usage: #{0} PATH (lines|words|find REGEXP)") unless ARGV.size >= 2
path, mode, optional_regexp = ARGV

open(path) do |fd|
  case mode
  when "lines"
    puts(fd.lines.count)
  when "words"
    puts(fd.lines.map { |line| line.split.size }.reduce(0, :+))
  when "find"
    if optional_regexp
      fd.lines.each { |line| puts(line) if line.match(optional_regexp) }
    else
      fail("mode find requires a REGEXP argument")
    end
  else
    fail("Unknown mode: #{mode}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips about idiomatic Ruby code. And thanks for the example. I know there was a "Ruby way" of doing it... short, compact, pragmatic, to the point, yet readable.

Comment: Upvoted.  Great answer.  One small suggestion for an improvement: Put all the argument checking and fail statements at the top.  Then the program reads: 1. data validation 2. actual content.  It has the added benefit of getting rid of all the "if... else" statements.

Answer (score 5):

## Formatting

Most Rubiest favor some white space between methods, such as:

```
class LineCounter

  # Initialize instance variables
  def initialize
    @line_count = 0
  end

  def process(line)
    @line_count += 1
  end

  def print_result
    puts "#{@line_count} lines"
  end

end
```

### {...} vs do...end

For multi-line blocks, prefer do...end:

```
File.readlines(arguments.path).each do |line|
  arguments.processor.process(line)
end
```

## Comments

Comments, when used, should say something the code doesn't already
say.  This comment, and some of the others, can be eliminated without
injuring the reader's ability to understand the code:

```
  # Initialize instance variables
  def initialize
    @line_count = 0
  end
```

## Argument parsing

You are correct that argument parsing in this script has the potential
to be improved.  There are a few different ideas that could help here.

### Separate class

I usually like to put argument parsing in its own class:

```
class Arguments

  attr_reader :path
  attr_reader :processor

  def initialize(argv)
    @path = argv[0]
    if argv.length == 2
      if argv[1] == "lines"
        @processor = LineCounter.new
      elsif argv[1] == "words"
        @processor = WordCounter.new
      end
    elsif argv.length == 3 && argv[1] == "find"
      word_to_find = argv[2]
      @processor = WordMatcher.new(word_to_find)
    end
    if not @processor
      print_usage
      exit 1
    end
  end

  private

  def print_usage
  puts "Usage: #{$0} <file> words|lines"
  puts "       #{$0} <file> find <what-to-find>"
  end

end
```

The main program becomes:

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  arguments = Arguments.new(ARGV)
  File.readlines(arguments.path).each { |line|
    arguments.processor.process(line)
  }
  arguments.processor.print_result
end
```

I had more I was going to write, but after seeing the simplicity of @tokland's answer, I think the approaches I was going to take are not so good.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Interesting approach with your Arguments class... Have you considered using a special library for command-line argument validation?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, I did.  optparse, of course, only takes care of switch (`--foo`) arguments, so it would be no help.  I have often looked for libraries which do good handling of non-switch arguments; I am not aware of one that _just_ parses arguments.  The ones I've seen have strong opinions on parts of your program that are not argument parsing.

Answer (score 5):

As you have not indicated whether you are looking for a quick and dirty--possibly one-off--solution, or production code, and have said nothing of file size, I decided to suggest something you could employ for the former purpose, when the file is not humongous (because I read it all into a string):

```
fname, op, regex = ARGV
s = File.read(fname)
case op
when 'rows'
  puts s[-1] == $/ ? s.count($/) : s.count($/) + 1
when 'words'
  puts s.split.size
when 'find' 
  regex = /#{regex}/
  s.each_line {|l| puts l if l =~ regex}
end
```

where `$/` is the end-of-line character(s).  Let's create a file for demonstration purposes:

```
text =<<_
Now is the time
for all good
Rubiests to
spend some
time coding. 
_
File.write('f1', text)
```

If the above code is in the file 'file_op.rb', we get these results:

```
ruby 'file_op.rb' 'f1' 'rows'  #=> 5
ruby 'file_op.rb' 'f1' 'words' #=> 13
ruby 'file_op.rb' 'f1' 'find' 'time'
  #=> Now is the time
  #   time coding.
```

Comment: Thanks for the super-compact solution. It is a good example and serves me well, however I would like to show an "usage" text in case of missing / incorrect arguments. But please don't change your example! I like it that it's so short.

Comment: I think you can remove the `+ [nil]`. Unlike Python, you can de-struct even if sizes do not match.

Comment: Sebastian, I figured you could add whatever data checks you wanted.  @tokland, thank you-good to know that, edited my answer--and I'd also like to thank Ruby.